# Magento up-sell block not displaying

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I need to display the up-sell block in my product page.
Currently, I have the following code at the bottom of the file `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

I have successfully set products in the CMS, and have disabled all caches.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have come across the situation where you have assigned Up-sells, cross-sells or related products to a certain product but when you go to the Frontend, you can’t see them this solution may help.

There maybe several reasons as to why such problem occurs i.e your theme doesn’t have the upsell, cross-sell or related product block enabled OR simply that the block is set to render on the right column layout but you are on left column layout.

However, if everything else seems to be in place but just a simple matter of you are not seeing the products, it maybe that your indexes are out of date. So simply:

```
Login to admin
System -> Index Management 
Select: Product Flat Data, Category Flat Data, Category Products
Reindex Data
```

http://www.magentodeveloperleedsuk.co.uk/upsell-cross-sell-and-related-products-not-showing-magento-frontend/

Comment: I have a custom theme, the cross-sells works in the cart page. I have reindexed the data in the admin panel and nothing changes. How can i add the up-sell block in my theme ? Or How can i know if the up-sell block is integrated ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to a magento category.  Then it will figure in Search and also in other modules like Cross and Up sell.